# Facebook api messing with jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, jquery-animate

So I'm trying to put a simple facebook like box in my website but it makes jQuery animations stutter. It seems the problem is that if both the loading of the Facebook API, and my animation take place at the same time, stutter happens.

I have tried using the iframe version and the JS version of the facebook api and both make simple fadeIn() go from 1 to 0 with almost no in between steps.

I can solve it by calling the facebook JS code after I've finished my animations... but this does not seems clean to me.

Is there a proper solution to this problem?
Like a different way of calling the facebook api?

This is the code I'm using from facebook

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

TIA